# Marklogic http post using ssl

Tags: ssl, marklogic

I am trying to do a **xdmp:http-post** to a third party URL using the Marklogic (v7.0) query console. The URL is a **https://** url and I was able to install the necessary certificate from the admin console. When I run the post, I am receiving the following error:

```
[1.0-ml] SVC-SOCCONN: xdmp:http-post("https://xxxxx.............", ()) -- Socket connect error: SSL_connect XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:60855-XX.XX.X.XX:443: key size too small (0x0506706e); DH lib (0x14098005)
```

Can you please assist me here as to what I might be doing wrong? Do I need to follow any additional steps apart from installing the certificate?

Please let me know if I need to supply additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server's certificate is using a key size that is too small, and therefore considered to be insecure. Since the host name suggests it's a dev machine, the best thing would be to have them use a longer key if you can.

If that's not possible, you can disable FIPS mode on your MarkLogic server. That can be done through the Admin UI by navigating to http://your.host.name:8001/cluster-admin.xqy?section=cluster&local-cluster=true and setting "ssl fips enabled" to false. Be aware that if you do this, the server will allow you to use ciphers and key lengths that are considered weak.